# Automatically open PDF in Preview when printing

Tags: cocoa, nsprintoperation, nsprintinfo

I'm setting jobDisposition to `NSPrintPreviewJob` in `NSPrintInfo`, but the value seems to be ignored. Instead of opening the document in Preview, the print operation displays the print panel as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go directly to preview, you need to suppress the print panel:

```
printInfo.jobDisposition = NSPrintPreviewJob;
NSPrintOperation *op = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:view
                                                      printInfo:printInfo];
op.showsPrintPanel = NO;
[op runOperation];
```